# SQL - group by, count

Tags: sql, group-by, order

Boa tarde, tenho atualmente o seguinte código e resultado. Gostava de em vez de ter este resultado, ter apenas uma linha para cada tipo (coluna 1), sendo esta linha aquela cuja coluna 4 apresentar o maior valor. Se alguém poder ajudar (sou principiante).

```
SELECT DISTINCT TIPO.NOME_TIPO_MERCADORIA AS TIPO, VEI.ID_VEICULO AS IDVeiculo, 
                VEI.MATRICULA AS matricula, COUNT(VIA.ID_VIAGEM) AS Viagens 
FROM VEICULO VEI, TIPO_MERCADORIA TIPO, VIAGEM VIA
WHERE VEI.ID_VEICULO = VIA.ID_VEICULO
AND VEI.ID_TIPO_MERCADORIA = TIPO.ID_TIPO_MERCADORIA
GROUP BY TIPO.NOME_TIPO_MERCADORIA, VEI.ID_VEICULO, VEI.MATRICULA
ORDER BY 1, 4 DESC;
/
```

[image: Resultado obtido aqui]

Gostaria que os resultados finais fossem apenas a 1ª e 3ª linha. Basicamente agrupar isto. Obrigado

Comment: Qual é o gerenciador de banco de dados: MySQL? Oracle Database? SQl Server? outro?

Comment: E você quer escolhe aleatoriamente um dos valores de IDVeiculo e outro valor de matricula para cada tipo?

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi, você consegue saber qual veículo fez mais viagens. Sendo assim, joga essa pesquisa numa *subconsulta* e a consulta principal é feita em cima do *id* do veículo (detalhe, a consulta funciona assim caso o mesmo não transporte tipos diferentes, como exemplificado na pergunta).

```
SELECT DISTINCT TIPO.NOME_TIPO_MERCADORIA AS TIPO, 
    VEI.ID_VEICULO AS IDVeiculo, 
    VEI.MATRICULA AS matricula, 
    COUNT(VIA.ID_VIAGEM) AS Viagens 
FROM VEICULO VEI, TIPO_MERCADORIA TIPO, VIAGEM VIA
WHERE VEI.ID_VEICULO = VIA.ID_VEICULO
  AND VEI.ID_TIPO_MERCADORIA = TIPO.ID_TIPO_MERCADORIA
  AND VEI.ID_VEICULO = 
    (SELECT TOP 1 VEI2.ID_VEICULO 
     FROM VEICULO VEI2, VIAGEM VIA2 
     WHERE VEI2.ID_VEICULO = VIA2.ID_VEICULO
       AND VEI2.ID_VEICULO = VEI.ID_VEICULO 
     GROUP BY VEI2.ID_VEICULO 
     ORDER BY COUNT(VIA2.ID_VIAGEM) DESC)
GROUP BY TIPO.NOME_TIPO_MERCADORIA, VEI.ID_VEICULO, VEI.MATRICULA
ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Para isso, você terá que usar uma `sub-query`:

```
SELECT TIPO.NOME_TIPO_MERCADORIA AS TIPO, b1.ID_VEICULO AS IDVeiculo, b1.MATRICULA AS matricula, b1.QTDE_VIAGENS AS Viagens
FROM TIPO a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT a1.ID_VEICULO, a1.MATRICULA COUNT(b1.ID_VIAGEM) QTDE_VIAGENS
    FROM VEICULO a1
    INNER JOIN VIAGEM b1 ON a1.ID_VEICULO = b1.ID_VEICULO
    WHERE a.ID_TIPO_MERCADORIA = a.ID_TIPO_MERCADORIA
    GROUP BY a1.ID_VEICULO
    ORDER BY QTDE_VIAGENS DESC
    LIMIT 1
) b1;
```